# Как найти числа в массиве, цифры в которых идут в строгом порядке возрастания?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть задача следующего толка:
Ввести с клавиатуры произвольное количество чисел затем найти и вывести в консоль числа, цифры в которых идут в строгом порядке возрастания. Например: `321 354 245 159 8`, нужно вывести `245 159`.
На данный момент пока не понимаю как найти эти самые числа... Вот мой пример кода:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Введите числа через пробел и нажмите Enter:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lineOfNumbers = scan.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = lineOfNumbers.split(" ");
    char[] element;
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        element = numbers[i].toCharArray();
        //что тут надо сделать???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше написать отдельный метод. По сути все что нужно, это итерироваться и следить за тем, чтобы предыдущее число всегда было меньше следующего.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Введите числа через пробел и нажмите 'Enter': ");
    Scanner scaner = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (String number : scaner.nextLine().split(" ")) {
        if (check(number)) System.out.println(number);
    }
}

private static boolean check(String numbers) {
    int prev = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (char ch : numbers.toCharArray()) {
        if (prev > ch) return false;
        prev = ch;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `if (prev >= ch)`

Comment: @Igor это уже от условия зависит. написано в строгом порядке возрастания. если нужно пропускать еще и равные числа, то действительно следует изменить на if (prev >= ch).

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: не "число", а "цифра".

Answer (score 0):

```java
// массив чисел
int[] arr = {321, 354, 245, 159, 8};
// IntStream по числам из массива
Arrays.stream(arr)
        // как минимум двузначное число
        .filter(i -> Math.abs(i) > 9)
        // Stream<String> число в виде строки
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        // сортируем символы в строке лексографически и проверяем
        // равна ли отсортированная строка исходной строке
        .filter(str -> str
                // IntStream по символам строки
                .codePoints()
                // сортируем символы (по возрастанию)
                .sorted()
                // без повторов (строгое возрастание)
                .distinct()
                // Stream<String> символ в виде строки
                .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                // объединяем символы в одну строку
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
                // сравниваем с исходной строкой
                .equals(str))
        // вывод в столбик
        .forEach(System.out::println);
//245
//159
```